# Proving $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\gt\sqrt{m+1}$

Tags: inequality, induction

well the original problem was to prove the sum of k to the negative one half was more that the square root of n but it thought it would be best to use induction and get the equation displayed above. I have somewhat of a solution but I don't think it's right and I'm new to this so I didn't know how to post my work for correction.I'd really like some feedback even if it's not an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(m):\displaystyle \sum_{1\le k\le m+1}\frac1{\sqrt k}>\sqrt{m+1}$ holds true for $m=n$

$\displaystyle\implies \sum_{1\le k\le n+1}\frac1{\sqrt k}>\sqrt{n+1}$

For $m=n+1$
$\displaystyle\implies \sum_{1\le k\le (n+1)+1}\frac1{\sqrt k}=\sum_{1\le k\le n+1}\frac1{\sqrt k}+\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}}$
$\displaystyle>\sqrt{n+1}+\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}} $ which needs to be $\ge \sqrt{n+2}$

$\displaystyle\iff\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}+1\ge n+2\iff \sqrt{n+2}>1\iff n+2>1$ which is true

Eastablish the base case i.e., $n=2$

Answer (score 1):

telescoping also works: note that: k^(-0.5) > 2((k + 1)^(0.5) - k^(0.5)) and sum k = 1 to m+1.

Answer (score 1):

Induction may not always be the best
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\frac1{\sqrt k}>\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\frac1{\sqrt{m+1}}=\frac{m+1}{\sqrt{m+1}}=\sqrt{m+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Looking at

[image]

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}}+\sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}} +\int_{x=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx $$ $$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}} + 2\sqrt{m+1} -  2  \gt \sqrt{m+1}$$ the last by the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.

Comment: note that $$ - 2 \sqrt m + \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{\sqrt k}  $$ has a limit as $m$ goes to infinity. Very similar to harmonic sum and Euler $\gamma.$ ...probably knew that.

Comment: @Will Jagy: Indeed the limit is close to $-1.46$: the sum of all the pink areas (about $0.54$ and obviously converging to a limit) minus $2$.  Euler's $\gamma$ is the similar sum of pink areas above a different curve.